# localhost doesn't resolve to 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, macos, localhost

I make a call to `Inet4Address.getByName("localhost")` expecting to see `127.0.0.1`, but instead I see my IP assigned to my ethernet/airport.  If I disconnect my ethernet/airport, I will get the resolution of `127.0.0.1`, but as soon as I connect again it resolves to the IP address of the ethernet/airport.

I'm using OSX 10.6.7 and java version "1.6.0_24".  My /etc/hosts file has `"127.0.0.1 localhost"`.  Ping localhost in the terminal does resolve to 127.0.0.1.

The reason I need this is that I'm doing GWT development where I have a different JVM trying to make a call to GWT Hosted Mode, and I get a ConnectionException: connection refused, if localhost doesn't resolve to 127.0.0.1.

Thanks

Comment: If you already know you have to go to 127.0.0.1 then just point to it instead of resolving. It can be platform specific since on my linux box it resolvs 127.0.0.1

Comment: I don't own the code that makes the call, but if I can't figure out how to make it work, I will be asking the people to make that change.

Comment: Try to capitalize as in "Localhost" and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost  In short, it seems a name resolution quirk.  On my machine (Mac OSX), I tried `ping 127.0.0.1`and `ping` with the IP address of my ethernet port; the timings looked the same.  That would suggest (I am not sure, maybe someone else can answer/confirm) that even if it shows an IP address assigned to an ethernet port, it does not send the data through the network.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was because my hostname was set to localhost. I changed it and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this behavior on MacOS (v10.9) when the hostname is not set. Go to to System Preferences -> Sharing and verify the computer name has a value filled in.

Note that using 127.0.0.1 is a workaround, but you probably want to sort this out properly, since localhost is supposed to be 127.0.0.1, and if it's not, other things (like database connections etc.) might break.

Answer (score 0):

Tangentially relevant for those who come after:

It may also be useful to confirm that you're requesting the proper port!

Pinging may work fine, but if you've got no web server listening on port :80, then you'll get no response in the browser... Monday morning gotchas, eh XD