# What is the difference between 127.0.0.1 and localhost

Tags: sockets, networking, dns, localhost

Assuming the following is defined in `.../hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

What, if any, are the actual differences between using `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` as the server name, especially when hitting processes running locally that are listening for connections?

Comment: You could say `localhost` is protocol independent, both IPv4 and IPv6 will work.

Comment: Another different is that most browsers treat `localhost` as a secure origin, whereas `127.0.0.1` is not treated as secure.

Comment: @user10833119 chrome and edge do not seem to treat localhost as secure and ff says page is stored on your computer.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Well, the most likely difference is that you still have to do an actual *lookup* of `localhost` somewhere.

If you use `127.0.0.1`, then (intelligent) software will just turn that directly into an IP address and use it. Some implementations of `gethostbyname` will detect the dotted format (and presumably the equivalent IPv6 format) and not do a lookup at all.

Otherwise, the name has to be resolved. And there's no guarantee that your `hosts` file will actually be *used* for that resolution (first, or at all) so `localhost` may become a totally *different* IP address.

By that I mean that, on some systems, a local `hosts` file can be bypassed. The [`host.conf`](http://tldp.org/LDP/nag/node82.html) file controls this on Linux (and many other Unices).

Comment: The main difference is that the connection can be made via Unix Domain Socket, as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1

Comment: `/etc/nsswitch.conf` selects if `hosts` or DNS is used first for a host lookup, if nss is running.

Comment: @DonViegues That's MySQL specific and IMO bad design. It will see localhost and tries to use unix-socket instead of connecting using IP but for 127.0.0.1 it just uses IP.

Comment: @ArmanOrdookhani AFAIK if you are connecting to a remote host via SSH and then from there to a MySQL (like a SSH tunnel to reach the MySQL server) you have to use 127.0.0.1, as the whole thing goes over TC/IP. But if 2 processes running on the same machine want to connect, localhost (unix socket) is faster/has lees overhead. Thanks!

Comment: @DonViegues Yeah you are right unix socket has less overhead than TCP/IP. I just wanted to mention this behaviour is specific to MySQL and not something in OS or networking level.

Answer (score 66):

[Wikipedia sums this up well:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)

> On modern computer systems, localhost as a hostname translates to an IPv4 address in the 127.0.0.0/8 (loopback) net block, usually 127.0.0.1, or ::1 in IPv6.

The only difference is that it would be looking up in the DNS for the system what `localhost` resolves to. This lookup is really, really quick. For instance, to get to `stackoverflow.com` you typed in that to the address bar (or used a bookmarklet that pointed here). Either way, you got here through a hostname. `localhost` provides a similar functionality.

Comment: This is actually important. localhost can resolve to an IPv6 address, whereas 127.0.0.1 cannot. Using localhost on an IPv6 only system can work, whereas 127.0.0.1 will not since IPv4 is not available.

Comment: On my Windows10 system the DNS lookup is really, really slow, about 1100 milli secs. So I switched to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 40):

Some applications will treat `localhost` specially.

For example, the MySQL client will treat `localhost` as a request to connect to the local Unix domain socket instead of using TCP to connect to the server on `127.0.0.1`.  This may be faster, and may be in a different authentication zone.

Answer (score 11):

Well, by IP is faster.

Basically, when you call by server name, it is converted to original IP.

But it would be difficult to memorize an IP, for this reason the domain name was created.

Personally I use `http://localhost` instead of `http://127.0.0.1` or `http://username`.

Comment: localhost is faster, is does not use TCP/IP

Comment: @Don Viegues - what you say is contradicted to the other answers in this thread. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I will copy and paste other comment of mine: The main difference is that the connection can be made via Unix Domain Socket, as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715925/localhost-vs-127-0-0-1

Comment: @DonViegues that is specific to MySQL, which is handling `localhost` in a [special way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Special_cases). Other applications will likely still lookup `localhost`.

Comment: If Mysql hosted on Windows computer, it could be a big difference. Connection by IP address could be much faster in that case.

Answer (score -8):

There is nothing different. One is easier to remember than the other. Generally, you define a name to associate with an IP address. You don't have to specify localhost for 127.0.0.1, you could specify any name you want.