# How to redirect a url to localhost?

Tags: localhost, windows-server-2008-r2, ipv6, ipv4

I want to do some testing on my Windows 2008 R2 server. That is, let a URL redirect to `localhost`.

For example, let `"http://mysample.mydomain.com/index.html"` actually accesses "http://localhost/index.html". Is there any way I can do this?

I tried to edit the `windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file, adding `127.0.0.1 -> mysample.mydomain.com` mapping, but it doesn't work. It seems `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` are not identical. 
I can access "http://localhost/index.html", but I can't access "http://127.0.0.1/index.html"!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this should be migrated to superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Write class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page then override on load:

```
public abstract class CorePage : Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        //TODO: check request url and make a redirect if required!

    }
}
```

Change all your pages to inherit from CorePage and job is done! This will of course work only for aspx pages on application level not for entire IIS.

Comment: I want to do this with my IE.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a Windows 2008 R2 server, I guess you are using IIS for your test. Also note that Windows Server 2008 is the first version of Windows to "enable" IPv6 by default - but is your IPv4 version enabled too...?

```
Enable IPv4: [Control panel > Network and sharing center > Change adapter settings > Right click the adapter used for connectivity and select properties > See if IPv4 is checked. ]
```

I think your localhost is internally been resolved to use ::1 (IPv6) loopback address. You can confirm this by checking:

For IPv6 test: `ping localhost -6` and for IPv4 test: `ping localhost -4`. If it resolves to ::1, its using the IPv6 address.

Your \etc\hosts file should have the following entries:

```
::1 locahost mysample.mydomain.com
```

Now do a ping test as `ping mysample.mydomain.com -6`. This should confirm that mysample.mydomain.com has been resolved to your local loopback 
address using IPv6.

Refer:

1. [Difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)
2. [Localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)