# AJAX-Request combined with cURL and PHP takes too long to load

Tags: php, ajax, curl, pdo

I am working on my local machine with xampp and every other ajax request works very well and fast. My current application takes **21 seconds** to load 3.5 kilobyte of data.

This is a bit slow if you ask me. So what is my software doing?

The software has 4 radio buttons. The user chooses one and then an ajax-request is created

```
var radio = $('input[name="selection"]:checked').val();
var hidden = $('#hiddenFive').val();
$.ajax
({  
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'curl.php',
    data: {type: radio, region: 'Hampshire', hidden: hidden},
    success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        var strin = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        {
            strin += "<b>Name of " + radio + ": </b>" + obj[i].name + "<b> | Region: </b>" + obj[i].region + "<br>";    
        }
        $('#result').html(strin);
    },
    error: function(response, status, error)
    {
        alert("Error"); 
    }
});
```

The data gets sent to the site curl.php which sends a curl request to an *external* web site. I wrote external cursive, because it is on the same folder, we should just act like it is external and we need data with `cURL` from it (Homework you know)

So, now, the URL looks like this

```
http://localhost/htmlAssignment/5/curl.php?type=town&region=Hampshire&hidden=hiddenFive
```

And the curl.php saves those parameters in variables and then sends it to the web service.php

```
<?php
$type = $_GET['type'];
$region = $_GET['region'];
$hidden = $_GET['hidden'];
$url = "http://localhost/htmlAssignment/webservice.php?type=" . $type . "&region=" .$region. "&hidden=".$hidden;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
echo $output;
?>
```

The webservice.php

checks if the hidden-value is hiddenFive, what is correct and then calls a db-function

```
if(isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_GET['region'])  && $_GET['hidden'] == 'hiddenFive')
{
    $array = array();
    $region = $_GET['region'];
    $type = $_GET['type'];
    $array = $db->getMultiDataPOI($type, $region);
    echo json_encode($array);           
}
```

My db function looks like this

```
function getMultiDataPOI($type, $region)
    {
        $getMultiSQL = "SELECT ID, name, type, country, region, lon, lat, description FROM pointsofinterest WHERE type = :type AND region = :region";
        $getMultiPrepare = $this->prepare($getMultiSQL);
        $getMultiPrepare->bindParam(':type', $type);
        $getMultiPrepare->bindParam(':region', $region);
        $getMultiPrepare->execute();
        $getMultiResult = $getMultiPrepare->fetchAll();
        return $getMultiResult;
    }
```

After those 20 seconds the data gets displayed normally and as it should, but it takes 20 seconds, what is ab it odd if you ask me. What could be the problem here for that long time? As I said I'm working on localhost with xampp and any other AJAX-request which uses the same webservice loads instantly. Why does this take so long?

Here is a screen if it helps from FireBug. I  hope you can read it.

[image: FireBugScreen of Request]

Comment: Do you have your column being indexed looks like query is taking long time.

Comment: Start isolating bottom-up. First benchmark the innermost functionality (the DB function), then move up to the webservice, etc. etc. This should point out exactly where the slowness starts to occur. When you've located the problem it's much easier to debug - right now it's just a guessing game for us as well.

Comment: Why don't you call directly your webservice ?

Comment: @LucienBaron - Because my teacher wanted that we learn to use `cURL`. I have the exact same task without curl and there it works without problems.

Comment: There are **a lot** of technologies involved in your question: PHP, AJAX, CURL, MySQL, PDO... Please, narrow your question down to once certain problem. At the moment it is being not a real question and have to be **closed**. Please read FAQ on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Niels - That's what I did, I checked every line but can't seem to find the problem. I changed the database only to select those things i really need and re-read my ajax-request, but doesn't seem like I find something there

Comment: @YourCommonSense - The problem is that I used all those things. PHP for the web service, ajax for the request to the site that handels curl and PDO and MySQL for the database. The problem is that I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: @devShuba I didn't suggest reading the code line by line. I suggested chopping your code up in separate blocks so you have an actual idea where the delays are. That's the only way to solve slowness - finding out where the slowness is, if need be isolated to a single line of code, not 500.

Answer (score 0):

Just from my experience, I've found localhost to often cause strange behaviour, such as what you're describing. Have you simply tried changing your reference of localhost to 127.0.0.1 and use that? Localhost has to still do a name lookup, which can sometimes be unreliable from your hosts file, see [What is the difference between 127.0.0.1 and localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

Also I would try to open the PHP service file directly, the one you're calling in your AJAX, to make sure it loads fast by itself. Since it's doing an SQL query, there could be something with your query or even your MySQL configuration that's causing you some lag.

On another note, I'd use caution with your webserver.php file. All your request data is not being filtered and going directly into your DB which leaves your application open to SQL injections.

Comment: You don't need to worry about SQL-Injection. It's true that I'm just saving the get-parameters in variables but they get escaped in the database anyway by `bindParam`. I already changed it to 127.0.0.1 but this leaves no difference. But thanks!