# jboss-as-7.1.1.Final : localhost:8080 not working

Tags: jboss, localhost

I downloaded the jboss-as-7.1.1.Final from : http://jbossas.jboss.org/downloads
I extract it to : C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
I create JBOSS_HOME = C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

I run cmd as administrator and execute the standalone command :

```
C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0
Calling "C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx51
2M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml
    ===============================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
11:20:47,560 INFOS [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
11:20:48,163 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
11:20:48,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final     "Brontes" starting
```

When i go to the following URL:
http://localhost:8080
=> it doesn't work.

Have I missed something?
thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have anything deployed at the ROOT level? Otherwise `localhost:8080` won't display anything. Perhaps you should go to `localhost:9990/admin-console`.

Comment: perhaps you may not have deployed your web app at the root directory, Try 
     localhost:8080/{WEB_APP_NAME}

Comment: Now I am practicing with JBoss-AS-7.1.1.Final in Wins x64 native and changed the port 8080 to 9091 from standalone.xml, still the JBoss homepage not showing, and now I am going to start a bounty over it...because oracle is running on port 8080...Have I left something here to configure explicitly...

Comment: It with "It doesn't work" do you mean "I get 404 - File not found", It's because you still haven't deploy anything yet ;)

Comment: Anyway JBoss community project is now called WildFly http://wildfly.org. I suggest download WildFly 11.0.0 Final from here http://wildfly.org/downloads/ and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. If that solves the problem, you can edit your hosts file to add the localhost mapping. See [What is the difference between 127.0.0.1 and localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

Otherwise, try a telnet localhost 8080 from command line. It may be that your browser is trying to go through a proxy. On telnet, https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-telnet-2626026. Or any other option, read more here: https://superuser.com/questions/621870/test-if-a-port-on-a-remote-system-is-reachable-without-telnet

Still not working? please check that the log includes a line saying that the server is started and running, look for "listening" in the logs.