# Local Http request Android

Tags: android

I'm developping an app and I need to store the result of the game in my database. I'm gonna do a local server for that. I already saw how to send a request with android. I just want to know how to do it locally. I dont know anything in network so I would like to know if it's different from doing to a non-local server. I want to know if doing localhost:8080/mypage?params is gonna be all right or if I need to be on the same wifi spot to do it, or if I need to do something specific.

Thanks

Comment: It will be ok to call localhost or use local ip address

Comment: Doing `localhost` on any device will go to *itself*, that is networking 101

Comment: So itself is not good ? it's not my machine. I'm not on emulateur.

Comment: In the app running on an emulator use ip 10.0.2.2 to connect with your server that runs on the same pc as the emulator is running on.

Comment: If the aap runs on an android device your app should use the ip of the machine where your server is running on. Both devices in same network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comment said,

> Doing `localhost` on any device will go to itself

You need to use the server real IP. Probably, you have dynamic IP, that means your IP is going to change every time you reset your router, so you need to use a Dynamic DNS service, for example: http://www.dnsexit.com/

Moreover, you're going to need to open corresponding port in your router if the app is going to run out of your LAN.

As comment said:

> that is networking 101

Comment: Thanks for taking my answer :P Also, DNS isn't needed for a local network. A static IP is preffered

Comment: ok thank you. It's just for a test so I'm gonna put my ip directly but I'm gonna check your link anyway ;). Thanks

Comment: It may be networking 101, but there are subtle differences between 127.0.0.1 and localhost.  And there's a performance benefit to 127.0.0.1 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost

Comment: 'You need to use your real IP'. Pretty unclear as both Android device and PC have a real ip.

Comment: 'Moreover, you're going to need to open corresponding port in your router.' That is nonsense. In his LAN he does not have to do that.

Comment: 'Thanks for taking my answer.'.   Yes indeed. Strange things happen.

Comment: I did `url = "http://ip_address:port"` but I have a timeout error message. Any idea where it could come from ?