# What is the differences between the link "http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4950" and "http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex"

Tags: database, oracle

I am using Oracle Database Express Editor.  I am installing it on my computer. I believe that the above links show different meanings but I do not exactly know what exactly each link is for and when we should use.  Can you please explain to me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 127.0.0.1 and localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

Comment: Does not seem like a duplicate, not of that question. This question has more difference than only the host. Hopefully that was not the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` resolves to the IP address `127.0.0.1` which is the most commonly used IPv4 loopback address.

- http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex is the default URL of server
- `apex` is the database access descriptor (DAD) name. The DAD describes how HTTP Server connects to the database server so that it can fulfill an HTTP request.  It is the entry from your `dads.conf` file. The default value is apex.
- `f?p=` is a prefix used by Oracle Application Express
- `4950` is the application being called

Answer (score 0):

Only difference I see between the links is

1. usage of loopback IP address `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`
2. Usage of query string in one url.

`127.0.0.1` and `localhost` both refers to your local computer. You can as make your URL to be below. *Hostname* you can get by running command `hostname` in command prompt

```
http://<Hostname>:8080/apex
```