# Laravel app storage images failed to load and redirect to 404

Tags: php, image, laravel

I hosted laravel application on shared hosting server.
on server there are 2 folders :

- 1) laravelapp  -> contains (app,config,database,vendor...etc folders)
- 2) public_html -> contains (css,js,images,storage folders)

I use below code to upload image :

```
 if($request->hasFile('file')){
     $filenameWithExt=$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
     $filename=pathinfo($filenameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
     $extension=$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $fileNameToStore=str_slug($filename,'_').'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
     request()->file->move(public_path('storage/profile'), $fileNameToStore);
     $image="/storage/profile/".$fileNameToStore;
}
```

It is successfully upload file to `laravelapp/public/storage/profile` folder

I have created symlink to `laravelapp/public/storage` with `public_html/storage`

in database : imagepath is saved as `/storage/profile/user1.png`

in blade template i use : `<img src="{{$img}}" />`

but imageurl :

> www.mydomain.com/storage/profile/user1.png redirect to 404 page and image not displaying .

anyone please help me to solve problem.

Comment: Try this: `<img src="<?php echo asset($img)?>"></img>`

Comment: it is also not working

Comment: Have you used this? `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: yes , i have creted symlink

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: im using laravel 5.5

Comment: According to Laravel 5.5 docs, your publicly accessible files should be put in directory

`storage/app/public`
To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public.`

`ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/app/public /path/to/laravel/public/storage`
Now you can create in your view an URL to the files using the `asset` helper:

`echo asset('storage/file.txt');`

Comment: You can see more info from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view/30191854   Hope it'll help you!

Comment: @HirenGohel , bhai thanks for help & support :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) To store file in  laravelapp/storage/app/public/cover/ folder

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
 $path=$request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images',$fileNameToStore);
```

> 2) To store file in laravelapp/public/cover/ folder

```
 $path=request()->cover_image->move(public_path('storage/profile'), $fileNameToStore);
```

in shared hosting server there are 2 folders :

laravelapp and public_html

As im using 2nd way to upload image , I have solved this issue by creating symlink from laravelapp/public/storage folder to public_html/

```
ln -s /home/username/laravelapp/public/storage  /home/username/public_html/
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me on a shared hosting server:

edit your `config/filesystems.php` and modify the `public` part like this

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
```

Notice that the storage_path() does not take any argument. Now remove `storage` folder from your `public` directory if already exists, then do:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: It worked for me, root part needed to be this statement : 
'root' => storage_path('app/public'),

Answer (score 5):

So, as per our discussion in comments and according to `Laravel 5.5` docs, your publicly accessible files should be put in directory `storage/app/public` To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public.`

```
ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/app/public /path/to/laravel/public/storage
```

Now you can create in your view an URL to the files using the `asset` helper:

```
echo asset('storage/file.txt');
```

Hope this will helps you and other users!

Answer (score 1):

is posible that the symlink of your storage/public folder was wrong, you can review if this is pointing to the correct folder Use the ls -l command to check whether a given file is a symbolic link, and to find the file or directory that symbolic link point to.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 16  2020 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

The first character “l”, indicates that the file is a symlink. The “->” symbol shows the file the symlink points to.

The rm command removes given files and directories. To delete a symlink, invoke the rm command followed by the symbolic link name as an argument:

```
rm symlink_name
```

create a new symlink to the storage public folder

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

In cPanel or any live server make sure your storage folder and subfolders have the correct permission right. It should be `644, 755 or 777`

Answer (score 0):

Since i get used to work on localhost with xampp

I had to add parameter for fix assets url to localhost at .env in main directory of project

```
ASSET_URL=http://localhost/project_name
```

I use storage system so more detailed i make url like

```
http://localhost/project_name/public/storage
```

So i can use `<?= asset('custom_directory/images/brand.png'); ?>` to obtain url

I also changed db_host, and memchached_host, also redis_host to localhost to make sure everything goes on with xampp

```
DB_HOST=localhost
MEMCACHED_HOST=localhost
REDIS_HOST=localhost
```

As long you use xampp we should respect apache and mysql database and give them localhost isntead of 127.0.0.1 since they treat it diffrently

[What is the difference between 127.0.0.1 and localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.