# Understanding the difference between localhost:8080 and 127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, server, localhost

I am trying to create an autocomplete search bar for a website I am making, but I keep running into the same issue. It functions as it should when I launch the Brackets live preview which prompts 127.0.0.1:..../.../.../ but when I press my home button which routes me to localhost:8080/.../.../, it doesn't seem to run the code. I think it has something to do with the jQuery call, telling the function in which circumstance to run, but I'm not entirely sure. I am using XAMPP.

`function autocomplete(inp, arr) { ... }`

Why does this occur?

Can you explain the difference between the two?

Comment: `localhost` is generally the address `127.0.0.1` but the `:8080` part means to connect to port 8080 instead of the default port 80.

Comment: So `localhost:8080` is the same as `127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: `127.0.0.1:8080` will be the same as `localhost:8080`, not plain `127.0.0.1`. Port 8080 is a popular port to host things like angular apps, nodeJS scripts, et cetera.

Comment: @Pointy @Shilly Ok, that makes sense. When brackets launches live preview, the url shows `http://127.0.0.1:49684/.../.../ ` Why does the autocomplete work at that address, but not `http://localhost:8080/.../.../` Can I provide any other information to be of help?

Comment: A web server listens generally on only one port. Looks like your numeric address is using port 49684, not port 8080. A "port" is like a room number in a hotel: the hotel itself has a street address, but when you rent a room you get a particular  room number

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost) can help you. A resume of that:

If you use 127.0.0.1, then (intelligent) software will just turn that directly into an IP address and use it. Some implementations of `gethostbyname` will detect the dotted format (and presumably the equivalent IPv6 format) and not do a lookup at all.

Copy of this answer*

Answer (score 0):

You are not using port 8080 when you access the site with ip so I assume your site is listening on port 80. Can you try http://localhost only without the port number

Comment: I tried using localhost and its returns **Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.** The project is located in my htdocs folder.

Comment: Can you check your host file there should be an entry like 127.0.0.1   localhost  host file can be found at windows\driver\etc folder

Comment: I'm pretty new to software development. I am using the XAMPP network. I'm not entirely sure where/what the host file is?

Comment: On Linux - /etc/hosts

Comment: On windows - The hosts file for Windows is located in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts .

Comment: What about on a Mac?

Comment: /private/etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

localhost will usually resolve to 127.0.0.1, but not always.

In normal configurations, localhost will point to either an address in the 127.x.x.x range (usually 127.0.0.1), or ::1 or similar if using IPv6.  Some application implementations actually treat localhost specially, and when used can trigger a connection using something other than the IP stack (like shared memory, etc).  Some IP stacks don't treat localhost as a special name, and you can manually have it resolve to any IP address you want.  For example, by putting an entry into your hosts file.

But your problem is that when you used localhost, you specified port 8080, and when you used 127.0.0.1 you didn't specify a port, which would default to either 80 or 443 depending on if you used the http or https prefix.

127.0.0.1 is (usually) the equivalent of localhost
127.0.0.1:8080 is (usually) the equivalent of localhost:8080

Comment: When I launch Brackets live preview, it uses 127.0.0.1: (Random Port). How do I specify the port 127.0.0.1: 8080? When I click on my home button, it references me to my home which is localhost:8080 because that is what the XAMPP network I downloaded runs on. I still don't totally understand why the autocomplete doesn't work on the localhost:8080, but does on the 127.0.0.1: (Random Port). Other functions of the JavaScript file work properly, why not this one?. Sorry if this is redundant, but it's a little difficult to understand as a new developer.