# Localhost redirecting to an external website

Tags: localhost, apache2, macos-high-sierra

My localhost (apache2) on Mac OS High Sierra suddenly starts redirecting to https://wmich.edu/cs. It seems like localhost is resolving to the external IP instead of 127.0.0.1. I visited the wmich website (using Firefox) last week. This is what I have tried so far:

-Accessed http://localhost from three different browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari) but all are redirecting to https://wmich.edu/cs.

-Cleared cache on the browsers

-Checked httpd.conf and .htaccess for any Redirection but couldn't find anything.

-Checked for any installed browser extensions, but there are none.

-Ran Avast Security but couldn't find anything

-Run cURL on terminal with the following output

curl -I localhost
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 04 Jul 2020 10:04:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://cs.wmich.edu/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

curl -I 127.0.0.1
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

-Ping localhost with the following output:

PING 127.0.01 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.097 ms

-Ping 127.0.0.1 with the following output:

PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.103 ms

-Stopped the web server altogether with "sudo apachectl stop" but the redirection still continues. cURL and ping are also giving the same output after the server is stopped.

I went over similar questions like the following but couldn't find a solution

[Suddenly my localhost website redirects to some hosting company's website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250073/suddenly-my-localhost-website-redirects-to-some-hosting-companys-website)
[localhost doesn't resolve to 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985034/localhost-doesnt-resolve-to-127-0-0-1)

Comment: Maybe have a look in the following file /private/etc/hosts and verify there is no reference to https://cs.wmich.edu/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no reference to the cs.wmich.edu in hosts

Comment: and if you simply use spotlight from your mac os, for example via the command line interface it would be something like : mdfind 'cs.wmich.edu'

Comment: Tried that too. No relevant results