# InetSocketAddress for localhost

Tags: java, sockets, localhost, inet, inet-socket

When I tried executing the code `new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 3000);` in java 13, the host is being resolved to `localhost/127.0.0.1:3000` instead of resolving to `localhost:3000`.

Any idea why it is being resolved with the IP address of localhost (i.e. 127.0.0.1) along with the `localhost` in the host address?
Because of this issue, I am not able to connect to the desired server and resulting to an UnknownHostException in java.

Comment: `InetSocketAddress` does not resolve into an HTTP url, so where are you actually getting that from? `InetSocketAddress` will resolve the specified hostname into an IP address, period, nothing more.  So wherever you are getting `http://localhost/127.0.0.1:3000` from, that is not coming from `InetSocketAddress` itself

Comment: Maybe related: [localhost doesn't resolve to 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985034/)

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use this instead? `new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 3000);`

Comment: Thank you Remy, I tried doing that as well. Its resolving to `localhost/127.0.0.1:3000`

Comment: Where are you getting the information that it is being resolved to `localhost/127.0.0.1:3000`? What tool is telling you that?

Comment: I am using Java API `InetSocketAddress` to resolve to a hostname. I can see the member variable  `holder` of `InetSocketAddress` of type `InetSocketAddressHolder` has an `addr` member variable of type `Inet4Address` which is being set to the hostname.

Comment: @Vibha See WHERE exactly? WHAT are you using to look at that? You are looking at an *internal implementation* and expecting it to make sense? Unless `InetSocketAddress.toString()`, `InetSocketAddress.getHostName()`, and `InetSocketAddress.getAddress().(getHostName|getHostAddress)()` are returning the literal string `"localhost/127.0.0.1"` (which, frankly, should be impossible given how `Inet4Address` actually works), then I wouldn't worry about what is being held by the `InetSocketAddress`'s internals.

Comment: `localhost/127.0.0.1:3000` is the result of calling `toString()` on an `InetSocketAddress`. Solution: don't.